# How can i get the values of this Object?

Tags: javascript, object

Excuse my english, im from argentina.
I have an object in `JS` called `listaTurnos` (obtained from a `ajax` call)

```
var listaTurnos = []
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax/turnos2.ajax.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data: { item: "a" },
        success: function(data) {
            data.forEach(e => {
                listaTurnos.push(e["datos"])
            });
        },
        error: function(data) {
        }
    });
});
console.log(listaTurnos)
```

This is how it looks in the console:

```
[]
0: "{"title":"Agustin Guerra","start":"2020-03-12T10:30:00","end":"2020-03-12T11:30:00"}
↵"
1: "{"title":"Mariel Guerrieri","start":"2020-03-15T09:30:00","end":"2020-03-15T10:30:00"}
↵"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I don't know how get the values `{"title":"Agustin Guerra","start":"2020-03-12T10:30:00","end":"2020-03-12T11:30:00"}` for example.

I try with `for..in`, with `foreach` and `for`, without success.

```
listaTurnos.forEach(e => {
    console.log(e.title)
        // etc
});
```

Returns nothing

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(listaTurnos))
```

Returns []

```
for (let i = 0; i < listaTurnos.length; i++) {
    console.log(listaTurnos[i])
}
```

Returns nothing

> I'm really lost
>
> my goal is, from the object, to get the following structure

```
[
{
    title: 'Agustin Guerra',
    start: '2020-03-12T10:30:00',
    end: '2020-03-12T11:30:00'
},
{
    title: 'Mariel Guerrieri',
    start: '2020-03-15T09:30:00',
    end: '2020-03-15T10:30:00'
}

]
```

Comment: "to get the following string" - that's not a string ... `console.log(JSON.stringify(listaTurnos))

Returns []` ... chances are you're trying to access `listaTurnos` before the AJAX call is run - please show the code where `listaTurnos` is received and then accessed by the code you've tried

Comment: @JaromandaX I just edited my question

Comment: i'm not sure that i understood but listaTurnos[0] should return you your values. keep me updated pls

Comment: @Antoine553 I thought the same, but it returns ``undefined``

Comment: `listaTurnos` is populated asynchronously at some unknown time in the future, `console.log(listaTurnos)` happens BEFORE the request is even sent. The console appears to show `listaTurnos` as having data, but the console evaluates the output at the time you click on it, so it's not an actual representation of the data at the time of the console.log ... if you instead do `console.log(listaTurnos.length)` you WILL get zero there

Comment: You're right, ``console.log(listaTurnos.lenght)`` returns 0, but ``console.log(listaTurnos)`` return all the data. it´s weird